# optimize list view with albumart

Tags: android, listview, optimization, bitmap

My ListView Containing all songs with album art is very slow and it lags no matter how much i re size the album art Please Help And How To i get the indexable List to work on the songs Title. Android Beginner and Sorry For Bad English.
Thanks For Any Help

```
public class SongAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer{
private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";



private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


 public SongAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
    super(context, c,textViewResourceId);

    mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
 private Bitmap bitmap = null;
 private BitmapDrawable drawable = null;



@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView title1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titlelist);
    TextView artist1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistlist);
    ImageView album1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconlist);

    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
    String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
    long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
      StringBuilder titleBuild = new StringBuilder();
      titleBuild.append(title);
      if(titleBuild.length() > 35)
      {
      titleBuild.setLength(32);
      title = titleBuild.toString()+"...";
      }
      else
      {
          title = titleBuild.toString();
      }
      StringBuilder artistBuild = new StringBuilder();
      artistBuild.append(artist);
      if(artistBuild.length() > 35)
      {
      artistBuild.setLength(32);
      artist = artistBuild.toString()+"...";
      }
      else
      {
      artist = artistBuild.toString();
      }




      final Uri ART_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ART_CONTENT_URI, albumId);
        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
          InputStream in;

            try {
                if(bitmap != null)
                {
                    bitmap = null;
                    if(drawable != null)
                    {
                        drawable = null;
                    }
                }
                in = res.openInputStream(albumArtUri);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false);
                // bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resizedBitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                drawable = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_artwork);
            }

album1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
title1.setText(title);
artist1.setText(artist);
}







@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
}@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be selected
    for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                    if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(( getItem(j))), String.valueOf(k)))
                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(getItem(j)), String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
    return sections;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, the problem lies here:

```
 in = res.openInputStream(albumArtUri);
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false);
```

You should be performing the above operations in a background thread rather than on the main thread, otherwise they'll be blocking the main (UI) thread and make everything unresponsive.

Also, instead of loading the full resolution bitmap directly into memory, consider using `BitmapFactory.Options` to down-sample it first.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

You could also consider using this awesome image loading library (supports content provider uris): https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thank you for your help my list is smooth and doesnt lag anymore.